# Parse json data for <highlighting> tag to highlight a text in a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 32
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 21,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "description": "The matte finish waves on this wedding band contrast with the high polish borders. This sharp and elegant design was finely crafted in Japan.",
                "UID_PK": "8252",

            },
            {
                "description": "This elegant ring has an Akoya cultured pearl with a band of bezel-set round diamonds making it perfect for her to wear to work or the night out.",
                "UID_PK": "8142",

            },

        ]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "8252": {
            "description": [
                " and <em>elegant</em> design was finely crafted in Japan."
            ]
        },
        "8142": {
            "description": [
                "This <em>elegant</em> ring has an Akoya cultured pearl with a band of bezel-set round diamonds making"
            ]
        },

    }
}
```

This is JSON data I got from solr when i set `hl=true` and `hl.fl=description`. Here I got `docs` tag and  `highlighting` tag. I need to parse `highlighting` tag to highlight "elegant" in description field which is in `<em>` tag...one more thing is `UID_PK's(8252,8142)` in `<highlighting>` are generated dynamically each time. Please suggest how can I do this if I am getting JSON data as

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=20&q="+newquery+"&sort=price asc&hl=true&hl.fl=description&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&json.wrf=?", function(newresult){
```

and parsing it as

```
$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){
```

and

```
 $.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i,hitem){
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid: `"docs": [ 1.{`. `docs` and `highlighting` are no *tags*, they are *properties*. What is what you want to do now? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: @Felix Kling :i have edited json, now it is valid. my problem is i want to  get "elegant" highlighted in my search results, which i suppose i could get if i parse highlighting property upto <em>elegant<em>

Comment: @Felix Kling: Now my problem is how to go upto <em>

Comment: And the search results are which onces? Those in `docs`?

Comment: @Felix Kling: yeah, search results are in docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the response is always text and only the to be highlighted elements are enclosed in `<em>` tags and there is only one of them, you could do this:

```
var highlight = {};

$.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i, hitem){
    var match = hitem.description[0].match(/<em>(.*?)<\/em>/);
    highlight[i] = match[1];
});

$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i, item){
    var word = highlight[item["UID_PK"]];
    var result = item.description.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), '<em>' + word + '</em>');
    // do something with the result
});
```

This only works if `word` does not contain nay special regular expression characters ([in which case you'd have to escape them](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/)). If you know that the to be highlighted word only occurs once in the search results, you don't have to use regex:

```
item.description.replace(word, '<em>' + word + '</em>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/taL8x/)

Comment: Felix Kling: Can i use hitem.description[0] because description is inside "8252",  i am unable to get this description :(

Comment: @Romi: That should actually work. `i` should be `8252` and `hitem` the corresponding element. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/bhXbh/

Comment: you used JSON.stringify((hitem.description[0])), what is this.

Comment: Felix Kling:when i put alert(word) in  $.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i, hitem){, then my jsp page is not working. script does not show any error but it is not running

Comment: @Romi: I just tried something. Works also without it: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/bhXbh/2/ . You have to put `alert(word)` after it was defined.

Comment: Felix Kling: yet i am debugging in the first .$each() loop, which is not working.the problem is in  hitem.description[0]

Comment: Felix Kling: i did this alert(hitem.description[0]) but its not working :(

Comment: Felix Kling: i tried it as $.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i,hitem){ alert(hitem.description[0]);});

Comment: @Romi: I made a slight mistake, try it again, and have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/taL8x/ . It works. If it does not work for you, the problem is somewhere else and I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Felix Kling: are you sure newresult contains my whole json data as you used in the demo. how can i be sure that newresult contains josn data

Comment: @Romi: Well, I used the data you posted in the question. Nothing more, nothing less. I changed it a bit because it is still not valid. You have a lot of commas before `}` or `]`, like at the end of `{"description": "...", "UID_PK": "8252",}`. You have to remove those. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @Flex: I am getting json data through $.getJSON(url, function(newresult){, as you can see in the question. i am asking is this newresult which i used in function(newresult) the jason data that you refer in demo as var newresult =

Comment: @Romi: Yes it is. Have a close look at it. Then you will see it is the same. As I said, I just removed the commas.

Comment: Flex: i juss posted some part of json data that is why it contained some error. but in my code i am getting it through getjson which as you said referring to newresult in function(newresult), am not getting why it is not working in my code then :(

Comment: @Romi: I don't know. Maybe if you can provide a link your page I can have a look at it.

Comment: Flex: its all working fine when i run my code through http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/3/ but in my jsp its not working :(. anyway thanks alot :) –