# Variable is not visible which gets the value in one loop and access in another loop in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// This function get the search results from Solr server 
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var query=getquerystring() ; //get the query string entered by user
        // get the JSON response from solr server 
        var newquery=query;
        
        
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+query+"&spellcheck=true&json.wrf=?",
                async:false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(newresult){
                    var html="<table><tr>"
                    var count=0;
                    var alt="NoImage";
                    var size="3pt";
                    var id;
                    var flag=1; // Flag for error messages 
                    border="1";
                    var n=newresult.response.numFound
                    var uid=new Array(n);
                    
                    // If no search results
                    if(newresult.response.numFound==0)
                    {
                     var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" >We're sorry, we found no results for <b>"+document.getElementById("queryString").value+"</font><hr />";
                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                /*  var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" >Total Results Found <b>  "+ result.response.numFound+"</b> for "+"<b>"+document.getElementById("queryString").value+"</b> keyword</font><hr /> ";*/
                // Parse solr response and display it on web page
                        $.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){
                    
                        uid[i]=item.UID_PK;
                        });
                        $.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i,item1){
                        
                        alert(uid[i]);
                    });
}
            });

            });
 // get the query string entered by user 
    function getquerystring() {
        var query=document.getElementById("queryString").value;
        //qstr = escape(query);
        return  query;
     }
  });
```

in this `uid[]` which gets the value in

```
$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){

                        uid[i]=item.UID_PK;
      });
```

I want to access this `uid[]` in next loop

```
$.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i,item1){

                alert(uid[i]);
            });
```

but `uid[]` is not visible in second `each()` loop, the alert shows undefined here. Why is so? What I need to do to make `uid[]` visible in second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One  test to be sure that the problem lies somewhere else:

1)are you sure that item.UID_PK contains something?To be sure do this:

```
$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){

                        uid[i]=item.UID_PK;
                         alert(item.UID_PK);

      });
```

Moreover what are you iterating on?is item an Object?

EDIT - looking at what your json is the problem is that in you second each you are iterating over an object and so your index (i) is a property. (in your case i is equal to 8252 and 8142) so you are accessing uid[8152] and uid[8142].

i'd do something like this:

```
var uid;
$.each(newresult.response.docs, function(i,item){
                  uid=newresult.highlighting[item.UID_PK];
                      $.each(uid, function(l, desc){
                              alert(desc[0]);
                       });

           });
```

alerts  `and <em>elegant</em> design was finely crafted in Japan.` and `This <em>elegant</em> ring has an Akoya cultured pearl with a band of bezel-set round diamonds making`

look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6ZvT/

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: yes i am very sure item.UID_PK contains data. i have already checked it. and yes item is an object

Comment: Nicola Peluchetti: for the corresponding json check my question  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450102/parse-json-data-for-highlighting-tag-to-highlight-a-text-in-a-field

Comment: When an answer satisfy you just accept it. I edited my answer, look if it helps